# Superpose two maps with different projections?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, projection, openlayers-5

I am attempting to superpose two different maps, but I am unable to superpose them and I have no idea on how to fix this issue.

```
    let bottom_left = ol.proj.fromLonLat([5.009752942020352, 45.356001339311526])
    let top_right = ol.proj.fromLonLat([11.484374748007156, 48.387198495867985])

    var projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:2056');
    var projectionExtent = [bottom_left[0], bottom_left[1], top_right[0], top_right[1]] // projection.getExtent();
    var size = ol.extent.getWidth(projectionExtent) / 1940;
    var resolutions = new Array(14);
    var matrixIds = new Array(14);

    for (var z = 0; z < 14; ++z) {
        resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z);
        matrixIds[z] = z;
    }

    // Tweak otherwise it does not work...
    resolutions = [8000, 3200, 1600, 640, 320, 160, 80, 64, 48, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1].map(x => x / 21.6 )

    let tilegrid = new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
        origin: ol.extent.getTopLeft(projectionExtent),
        resolutions: resolutions,
        matrixIds: matrixIds
    })


    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                extent: projectionExtent,
                url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                })
            }),
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                opacity: 0.7,
                source: new ol.source.WMTS({
                    url: 'https://sitn.ne.ch/mapproxy95/service',
                    layer: 'plan_cadastral_20180628', // 'plan_ville',
                    matrixSet: 'EPSG2056',
                    format: 'image/png',
                    projection: projection,
                    tileGrid: tilegrid,
                    style: 'default',
                    wrapX: true,
                    crossOrigin: "anonymous"
                })
            })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [773332, 5941674],
            zoom: 8,
        })
    });
```

As you can see the two maps almost superpose, but it seems the whole projection of either the swiss map or the open street map is wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EPSG:2056 must be defined using proj4 for the layer to reproject correctly over the OSM layer.  To ensure the WMTS layer was set up correctly I let OpenLayers obtain the options by parsing the WMTS capablities.

```js
  proj4.defs("EPSG:2056","+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");
  ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

  let bottom_left = ol.proj.fromLonLat([5.009752942020352, 45.356001339311526])
  let top_right = ol.proj.fromLonLat([11.484374748007156, 48.387198495867985])

  var projectionExtent = [bottom_left[0], bottom_left[1], top_right[0], top_right[1]];

  var parser = new ol.format.WMTSCapabilities();
  var map;

  fetch('https://sitn.ne.ch/mapproxy95/service/?Service=WMTS&Request=GetCapabilities').then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  }).then(function(text) {
    var result = parser.read(text);
    var options = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
      layer: 'plan_cadastral_20180628', // 'plan_ville',
      matrixSet: 'EPSG2056',
      format: 'image/png',
      style: 'default',
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          extent: projectionExtent,
          source: new ol.source.XYZ({
            url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
          })
        }),
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          extent: projectionExtent,
          opacity: 0.7,
          source: new ol.source.WMTS(options)
        })
      ],
      view: new ol.View({
        center: [773332, 5941674],
        zoom: 8,
      })
    });

  });
```

```css
html, body, .map {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```